# Distortion estimates to control Hausdorff measure of a curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-measure-theory, discrete-dynamical-systems

I am studying the paper [Blumenthal - Statistical properties for compositions of standard maps with increasing coefficent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09058).
I have a problem to understand how the distortion estimates are used. The setting is the following:
I have a family $\{ F_N\}$ of diffeomorphisms of the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$. Every map is associated to a number $L_N \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$. I define the family, for $K>M$
$$F_M^K:= F_K \circ \dotsb\circ F_{M+1} \circ F_M. $$
I take a curve $\gamma \in \mathbb{T}^2$ of the form $(x,g(x))$, $g \colon I_g \subset [0,1) \to [0,1) $. Now consider $J \subset I_g$ and set
$$ \tilde{\gamma}:= (F_M^{K})(\gamma\rvert_J).  $$
Briefly speaking, but it is not relevant to the question, in the paper the geometry of the map is such that I can still write this curve $\tilde{\gamma}$ as of the form $(x,h(x))$.

In Lemma *2.7*(c) they prove that, if $p,q \in (F^K_M)^{-1}\tilde{\gamma}$ then
$$\frac{\lVert(dF_M^K)_p\rvert_{T\gamma}\rVert}{\lVert(dF_M^K)_q\rvert_{T\gamma}\rVert}= 1 + O(L_M).$$
This is called distortion estimate.
What I do not understand, is how do they use this estimate in the rest of the paper?
In proposition *2.8*, they claim
$$\int_{\tilde{\gamma}}\frac{d\mathrm{Leb}_{\tilde{\gamma}}}{\lVert dF_M^{K} \rVert  \circ F_M^{K}} X_{R_{i,j}}\circ F_M  =  (1+O(L_m))
\mathrm{Leb}_{\gamma}((F_M^K)^{-1}\tilde{\gamma})\int_{\tilde{\gamma}} X_{R_{i,j}}\circ F_M$$
and they claim this identity follows directly from the estimate in lemma *2.7*(c). (What is $R_{i,j}$ is irrelevant to my question.)

My questions are the following:

(1) How do they derive this identity using the distortion estimate?

(2) Can anyone provide a formal definition for the "Lebesgue measure" in a curve $\mathrm{Leb}_{\gamma}$ as used in the paper?

(3) What is the relation between this definition of Lebesgue measure on the curve and the distortion estimates?

Comment: I think your final equality must be wrong with the indices. Distortion inequalities are a fancy gadget to control derivatives, in particular in this case - the appropriate Jacobians you get from the obvious change of variables under the dynamics.
For 2 - this is the push-forward of the 1 dimensional Lebesgue measure from [0,1) to the graph by the map (x,g(x)).
For 3 - the distortion estimate is used to control the Jacobian.

Comment: can you go more in details please? Where can I find reference for it?

Comment: how do you think is the true equality?

Comment: Also your notation doesn't make a lot of sense, what does it mean to post-compose the norm of some map after the inverse of the map?
Anyhow, Amie Wilkinson discuss distortion estimates in her (very preliminary) notes here - https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~wilkinso/papers/smoothergodictheory.pdf , probably any intro text about SRB measures will discuss similar concepts...